# Importing KML filename as attribute using FME?

Tags: kml, attribute-table, fme-form, batch

I have over 5,000 KML files where its name (*.kml) is crucial for my analysis: it contains the ID of that feature. I want to use the filename to populate a new field, or replace the existing content of the 'Name' or 'Description' fields.

I'm a geographer, so my programmer/command line skills are extremely low, although I don't think I'll get it done without it.

Any ideas?

Comment: FME (Safe Software) can manipulate the filename and attach this to attributes easily. see https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/20065/multiple-output-file-names.html

Answer (score 2):

Using FME 2016.1

1. Dynamic Reader (for KML)
2. Attribute Creator for ID and Populate with system parameter (SourceDataset)
3. Trim Folder name out (c:\temp in this case)
4. Trim .kml out of ID (leaves ID = 123)
5. write the KML out as 'ID.kml'

6.done will batch 5000 kml files.

[image]

After the comment:

Dynamic Writer can be created by adding a Google KML Writer then with 'Feature Type Definition:' drop list select Dynamic (Advanced)

[image]