# Using fme to create shapefile from several kmz files, labeling points in shapefile with name of kmz?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, kmz

I am trying to create a shapefile of point data. I have lots of kmz files each with a single point, and each named specifically. I'd like to end up with one shapefile of points all with a name attribute that is named for the original kmz file. Sort of a reverse fanout.

Comment: Use the attribute trimmer to get the file name of the kml and place it as part of the dynamic writer like here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195570/importing-kml-filename-as-attribute-using-fme/195577#195577

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straightforward in FME.  Firstly, I would generate a workspace from KML to Shapefile. For the reader dataset, click on the folder icon with they plus symbol.  Point to the folder containing your kmz files. On the writer, ensure you have selected Dynamic Schema.

[image]

For Feature Types to read, you only need Placemark which contains the point features:

[image]

In the format attributes for the reader, you want to expose fme_dataset which contains the filepath of each kml file.

[image]

From there, pass your features to a **[FilenamePartExtractor](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/filenamepartextractor.htm)**:

[image]

The Source Filename  will be the fme_dataset attribute. Here is where you can store the filename into an attribute of your choosing.  By default, the filename is `_filename` however, you can call it whatever you want.

[image]

The [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195570/importing-kml-filename-as-attribute-using-fme/195577#195577) linked to by @Mapperz would work too, but I prefer using a FilenamePartExtractor for this sort of thing.